# django import_export.. create view for importing data

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

i was trying to use django import-export module.. following the documentation [here](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.org/en).. i was able to make an export view.. but the import view is not working.. here's my code

----views.py-----

```
def dataset_export(request):
        ds=StudentResource().export()
        response=HttpResponse(ds.xls,content_type="xls")
        response['Content-Disposition']='filename=students.xls'
        return response

def dataset_import(request):
    dataset=tablib.Dataset(['', 'New book'], headers=['usn', 'name'])
    result=StudentResource().import_data(dataset,dry_run=False)
    response=HttpResponse(result,content_type="xls")
    return response
```

here's the student model

-----models.py-

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    usn=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    email=models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s(%s)'%(self.name,self.usn)
    class Meta:
        ordering=["usn"]
```

and the model resource

```
class StudentResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model=Student
        fields = ('usn', 'name', 'email')
        import_id_fields = ['usn','name','email']
```

Answer (score 0):

`import_data` returns `Result` object, and not xls file. You should probably render some template to inform user that import is finished or display errors.

For more info on `Result` class see:

https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/results.py

Comment: thanks for reply.. anyways i have used data-importer package for importing.. its much better and easier.